# Match index from arrayOne to arrayTwo

Tags: java, arrays

I'm looking to search arrayOne for a match, get the index value and then return the value from that index in arrayTwo.

Current code:

```
  private String [] sensorName = {"kitchenDoor", "glassCupboard", "microwave", "teaCupboard", "tap", "cutleryCupboard", "fridge", "kettle", "telephone", "plateCupboard", "chair", "sofa", "remote", "livingRoomDoor"};
  private int [] defaultSensorState = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
  private int [] prepareTea = {1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};

  public String getIndexValueName(int[] sensorArray, String[] nameArray, int index) {
    String sensorName = null;
    for(int i = 0; i < defaultSensorState.length; i++) {
      if(sensorArray[i] == index) {
        sensorName = nameArray[index];
      }
    }
    return sensorName;
  }
```

Method call:

```
getIndexValueName(prepareTea, sensorName, 2);
```

If I pass in the value `0` or `1` as the index it works fine, but any value higher than that it returns `null`.

EDIT:

To clarify with an example: I am looking to loop through the array `prepareTea` if a `1` is found I am looking to return index[x] that the `1` is in. I think want to search array `sensorName` and return the string that index[x] contains.

Comment: Because the array has only 0 and 1 values... Totally make sense.

Comment: How can I modify it to get, say index 3, regardless of the value?

Comment: Do you want to get nameArray with the index you have in prepareTea array?

Comment: Also when I pass in `0` it returns the first index, when I pass in `1` it returns index [1].

Comment: I think you are somehow misusing the "index" variable. Think about your logic thoroughly and use a debugger.

Comment: can you make your specification clearer? Which array do you want to search and which one get the value from?

Comment: I've added additional info to the question.

Comment: What I dont understand is why you dont have a class called Sensor with three properties (name, state, and prepareTea) and have an array Sensor? what you are doing does not make much sense

Comment: I've read through your code multiple times now and still having trouble understanding what's going on

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use something like the following and pass it to your function instead of `prepareTea` array:

```
private int[] sensorArray = {0,1,2, ...}

getIndexValueName(sensorArray, sensorName, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

My mistake was the `if` statement which need to be:

`if(sensorArray[i] == 1) {`

instead of

`if(sensorArray[i] == index) {`

Comment: this makes sense ;-)

Comment: I still don't understand what the author was trying to do.